# bicep passthrough output from another module

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have two modules. Module1 I have no control over how it is made or changes to it. Module2 uses Module1 and outputs some values from itself and form Module1.

I am trying to find a way to passthrough the values from Module1 through Module2 in an agnostic fashion.

This is what I mean:

**Module1.bicep**

```
//I have no control over this module and the changes made here

output One string = 'One'
output Two string = 'Two'
```

**Module2.bicep**

```
module module1 'Module1.bicep' = {
  name: 'Module1'
}

output Three string = 'Three'
output Foour string = 'Four'

//I would like to pass through the outputs of module 1

//This doesnt work!
//output Module1 object =  module1.outputs

//This works. But I would like to not change this if Module 1 changes
output Module1 object = {
  One: module1.outputs.One
  Two: module1.outputs.Two
}
```

Is there a way to abstract the output of Module1 though Module2 without having to list and group all outputs into an object?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah `output Module1 object =  module1.outputs` is adding the type of each property.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with simply accessing the individual outputs from `Module1` in your `Module2` file like so?

```
output One string = module1.outputs.One
output Two string = module1.outputs.Two
```

Alternatively, you could try:

`output Module1 array = module1.outputs`

(Not tried that, though!)

Comment: This return an error: Expected a value of type "array" but the provided value is of type "outputs".bicep(BCP033)

Comment: Accessing individual outputs from module1 is one way to do it. But since I have no access or control on changes to Module1.bicep, this way it ties me up to the Module1 and its changes. I was looking into a way to abstract that.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this successfully:

```
@description('Outputs from Module1')
output Module1 object = module1.outputs
```

You may just need to drill down to `.value` when accessing the values, e.g. `Module2.outputs.Module1.One.value`.